# What is wrong with my code checking for arithmetic sequence eligibility?

Tags: python, for-loop

When inputting a list of numbers, they would always result in True

```py
def arithmetic(lst):
    for i in range(0,len(lst)-1):
        if (lst[i+1] - lst[i]) != (lst[i+2] - lst[i+1]):
            return False
        return True
```

Comment: Please, post [mre], i.e. include sample of how you use this code

Comment: When and where do you return `True`? What does your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) have to say about it?

Comment: And once you fix that problem, you have to fix the list out of bounds issues you will then encounter.

Comment: Indentation matter in Python. Please edit your question and write your code in code block, with proper indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `return True` statement is inside the for loop it's gonna return true on the first iteration of the loop (even if the `if` condition is false).

You should remove indentation from that line, so that the `return True` is in the function, but NOT in the for loop.

Like this:

```py
def arithmetic(lst):
    for i in range(0,len(lst)-1):
        if (lst[i+1] - lst[i]) != (lst[i+2] - lst[i+1]):
            return False
    return True
```

But as mentioned by others in the comments this code will fail, cause you are trying to access elements outside the list. Hint `i+2` is the issue.

Homework would be:

- fix iteration issue by proper indexing
- think of better argument name and don't use abbreviations
- [OPTIONAL] by convention functions returning bool start with `is_`, `are_` and so on, it improves readability imho

Comment: Hi, say i have the sequence [3,6,9,11,14], doesn't this result in False straightaway on the 1st check? And if i have another example such as [3,6,9,12,15,18,21,26], this would result in True on the 1st check, but then it would go and check again the 2nd time to return False and subsequently replaces the True ? . This is implying on the original code that I wrote

Comment: Not sure I understand or you don't. I think your code is gonna return `True` on the first iteration always, unless the first three elements are not the sequence, then it's gonna return `False`, cause it's not even reaching the `return True ` statement